# Prove the following using partitions and lower sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Given partition $ P= {\{x_0,\ldots,x_n}\}, $and $ P'= {\{cx_0,\ldots,cx_n}\} $ assume $c>0$ are partitions on $[a,b]$ and $[ca,cb]$.

Prove that $\int_{ca} ^ {cb} f(x) \, dx= c\int_a^b f(cx) \, dx$

I am thinking of using lower sums of $f(cx)$ and f(x)$, but am lost in the direction to go about, for all we need to show is that they are equal, right?

Any help or attempt at a solution will help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what's the use of lower partitions in this case. First, note that $\,P\,$ is a partition of $\,[a,b]\,$ iff $\,P'\,$ is a partition of $\,[ca,cb]\,$ . Next, taking *any* points $\,d_i\in [cx_{i-1},cx_i]\,\,,\,\,i=1,\ldots,n$ , puting

$$||\Delta_P||:=\max_{i}(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(d_i)(cx_i-cx_{i-1})=c\sum_{k=1}^nf(d_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

Taking now the limit above when $\,n\to\infty\,$ while *also* $\,||\Delta_P||\to 0\,$ gives us the result.

Comment: If one can show that $c*L(f(cx),P)= L(f(x),P)$, one is done, which is essentially what you are doing, right? If you would be kind enough to walk me through it, I will be grateful. Also, I did not quite realize why are you taking the delta(p).

Comment: No, I'm not taking lower sums but only *sums*, and the delta converging to zero is a basic requirement in the definition of the Riemann Definite integral by means of Riemann Sums. "My" delta is what in other parts is called the partition's mesh or norm, and that it **must** go to zero is the same as requiring the sums' limit exist *while the partitions get finer and finer*...that's all.

Comment: I see, I was going a more Darboux route. Riemann's are not intuitive to me as much as Darboux is, although they are equivalent.